# Simulate a MERGE in Neptune's OpenCypher implementation

Tags: amazon-web-services, cypher, amazon-neptune, opencypher

I'm trying to run a `MERGE` query against an AWS Neptune database using their [new OpenCypher implementation](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/07/amazon-neptune-supports-opencypher/) but `MERGE` is [not yet supported as a clause](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-opencypher-limitations.html).

Is there a way to get the behaviour of a `MERGE` without using a `MERGE` in Neptune's OpenCypher implementation?

I'm hoping it's possible to do something like:

```
MATCH (ee:Person {name: "Sam"})

IF ee IS NULL THEN
  CREATE ...
ELSE
  SET ee += {...}
END
```

Obviously this is just pseudocode, but is there any way of achieving this behaviour without handling it in the application making the call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

openCypher does not provide a robust capability to perform the type of logic in a query that you show in your pseudocode.  Until `MERGE` is a supported clause in AWS Neptune the best way to achieve this functionality is to use the Gremlin pattern for this as described [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#element-existence). Neptune provides the ability to use both openCypher and Gremlin (via drivers or over HTTPS) on property graph data stored in Neptune.  For your pseudo code above the Gremlin equivalent would look like this:

```
g.V().
  has('Person', 'name', 'Sam').
  fold().
  coalesce(
    addV('NEW LABEL').property('propertyName', 'foo'),
    property('updateProperty', 'bar'))
```

UPDATE - As of the 1.1.0.0 version of Amazon Neptune the `MERGE` clause is now supported.